# giving a variable a unique name javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set up a function to run 1.5 seconds after a keyup event in a textarea. But, if another keyup event occurs in the same area I'd like to either extend the time to 1.5 seconds again or cancel the old function and update it with the new function.

To make things even more interesting xD
There are multiple textarea, each has their own unique ID. I'd like for it to only cancel if the keyup event is from the same textarea.

Here is an example of what I've been trying to do.

```
$(document).on("keyup",".edit_main textarea",function(e){
  location_val = //textareas unique ID 

  curval = $(this).val();
  blue = "blue";
  UNIQUE_VARIABLE = blue+location_val;

  clearTimeout(UNIQUE_VARIABLE);
  UNIQUE_VARIABLE = setTimeout(function(){
    // do cool stuff
  }, 1500);
});
```

This way it will only clear once, but it gets overwritten. So I tried using an array but I'm not sure that you can store a Timeout with that.

If my question is too vague, please say so and I will try to be more detailed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the timeout itself you would not need unique ids, you could use the [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) functionality of jQuery to have a unique timeouts for every element.

```
  $(document).on("keyup",".edit_main textarea",function(e) {
    var textArea = $(this);
    var curval = textArea.val();
    var blue = "blue";

    clearTimeout( textArea.data().keyupTimeout );

    textArea.data().keyupTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
      // do cool stuff
      textArea.val('the cool result');
    }, 1500);
  });
```

Comment: plus 1, although for completeness sake, it should be mentioned that directly assigning/reading a dynamic variable to/from the element (e.g. `this.keyupTimeout` ) would suffice

Comment: @Me.Name that's definitely true. But if jQuery is already used I still would suggest to use `.data()` as this will at least avoid name conflicts with DOM properties. It still might conflict with other plugins, but that's another problem.

Comment: @t.niese This is really close to what I'm looking for. Sorry I must have left out some details. Also whenever the function executes it should send the value of the original textarea.

Comment: @Mathew You indeed did, as you (at least I don't see it) didn't mention that in your question. I changed my answer according to your comment. You should read something about scopes and closures in js, these are really important parts you will need all the time.

Comment: @t.niese Works perfectly! And with so few lines of code! Thank you!! Although, I'm not entirely sure how the computer can tell the difference between variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is way more complicated than it needs to be. It seems you're having issues with [scope](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). Have a look at the documented code solution below. Also, you can take a look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3b9dg8L0/) as well. Hope this is helpful!

```
//This needs to be declared OUTSIDE the function.
var unique;

//No need to use $(document), target your textareas directly.
$('.edit_main textarea').on('keyup', function(e){

    //$(this) doesn't work here. Use e (an argument for the event). e.target.id gets the textarea's id.
    var location_val = e.target.id;

    //e.target.id returns just the id. 
    //We need to prepend the CSS selector for jQuery to find the element.
    var curval = $('#'+location_val).val();

    //I don't see the point of blue = 'blue', so I omitted it.

    //Clear the timeout first if any.
    clearTimeout(unique);

    //Set a new one.
    unique = setTimeout(function(){ 

        //Do something cool. Like telling you what's in the textarea.
        alert(curval); 

    }, 1500);   

});
```

Comment: Problem is: the OP asked to only cancel the timeout of the textarea on which the timeout was started, a single global variable will always cancel the timeout, also if the user types in another textarea.